# Does hibernate handle Spring annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hy guys.

I'm using lombok and spring annotation on my entities

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Podcast extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NonNull
    @NotNull @Size(max = 255) String title;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "podcast_id")
    @NonNull
    @NotNull Set<Episode> episodes = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I see lombok can handle spring annotation (@NonNull) but not the javax's one (@NotNull).

I wonder if hibernate can handle spring's annotation (@NonNull). Anyone know something about that ?

Comment: 'I wonder if hibernate can handle spring's annotation (@NonNull)' - handle *how*?

Comment: @crizzis Like if I have ```@Valid``` annotation, ```@NonNull``` will throw an error if the variable is null

Comment: AFAIK Only certain Spring APIs respond to `@NonNull`. Putting `@NonNull` on an entity field will not have any effect as far as Hibernate is concerned. You might want to use `@javax.validation.annotations.NotNull` instead, which *is* supported by Hibernate

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nonNull spring help me with my IDE which tell me potential NPE

Comment: No it won't. The `NonNull` from Spring serves a different purpose and is a configuration hint for the compiler NOT for checking at runtime. Hence it isn't a `NotNull` annotion which is handled by validation. Hibernate won't handle those either that is actual the java. validation part that handles those, for which hibernate has integration but it isn't hibernate that is handling those annotations.